# Seaborn kdeplot - update data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want to create a matplotlib widget, where i can update a plot by clicking on buttons, similar to this example: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/widgets/buttons.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)


class Index:
    ind = 0
    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        self.ind -= 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)

plt.show()
```

The only difference is, that i want to use a seaborn kdeplot (bivariate). See https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html

Since the `sns.kdeplot()` returns a matplotlib Axes object, i cant use `l.set_ydata()` as shown in the widget example.

I tried to do the plotting within the `next()` method. Since the current axis after clicking the button is the button-axis, the plot appears within the button, not the original axis. When i reset the current axis within  `next()` by calling `plt.subplot(111)`, the button will be overwritten by my plot.

How can i keep the buttons and update the kdeplot by clicking at the same time?

Comment: I think you're going to need to calculate the KDE yourself.